# Нереальная ошибка при компиляции android приложения

Tags: android, android-studio

При компиляции в ANdroid Studio выдает следующую ошибку: `Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'`.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Что же это такое?

Comment: Что делали перед этим? После каких изменений появилось данное сообщение?

Comment: Попробуйте вот так получить больше информации об ошибке: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21674403/3212712

Comment: Эксперементировал с библиотекой GraphView